# Can Looper.loop create multiple loopers

Tags: android, android-handler, android-looper

I would like to know whether Looper.loop() called multiple times creates multiple loopers??Please find my code below and let me know whether multiple loopers will be created because of this code.If yes then please give me advice to resolve this.

[image: code snippet]

Thanks in advance

Comment: here I am starting the thread multiple times because localThread.isAlive() returning false.

Comment: no, a Looper is created in `Looper.prepare` method, so there is only one `Looper`, if you start that `Thread` multiple times, you will have multiple `Looper`s but each one is associated with its corresponding `Thread`

Comment: Thank you pskink.But can you be more specific because i am getting it like" Starting my thread multiple times ==multiple loopers getting created".So i think that i am creating multiple loopers which act like zombies

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? are you aware of `android.os.HandlerThread` class? what is your goal?

Comment: I need to send mails when there is call so when one call comes i am receiving it through broadcast receiver and starting a async task  via looper thread.Now whenever there is a call i am starting a new thread which results in creating a new looper.I want to stop creating multiple loopers and use the one which is existing..

Comment: what do you need `Looper`s for?

Comment: If there are continuous calls then i need send mails continuously one after the other.So when looper is  executing for one call then the other will wait in the message queue till looper gets completed with the current one

Comment: @pskink Am i going wrong in using loopers for this case??

Comment: `Am i going wrong in using loopers for this case??` yes going wrong, use one `HandlerThread` instead